# Comparing outgoing mail options, self hosted VS google apps in my situation

Tags: smtp, hosting

I am setting up a small site that has the need to be able to programmatically send mail from time to time. Password resets and things like that. I'm already using google apps to handle my domains email, so now i'm left with the decision between setting up basic SMTP services on my server to send "password reset mails and things like that" OR instead to have the software use google apps to send mail.

I like the google apps option as it's less stuff to worry about and seems to fit my needs, i'm trying to figure out what the downsides would be?

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending limits come to mind as a drawback as currently they limit it to 2000 per day for each mailbox: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852

The above limit is for paid accounts and might be lower if you're using the free edition.

Comment: Good call, thanks, I went ahead and just did a basic postfix install to send mail from the server (send only), turned out to be easier than I thought

Comment: Be sure to set up reverse DNS, SPF records and DKIM, as you'll need them.